# Crashlytics not working IOS 10 Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, cocoapods, crashlytics

Hi I'm using Crashlytics to capture crash when user using app. I have made all installation through cocoa pods and successfully add app to Crashlytics dashboard. I manually force a crash using the template to one of my ViewController but I did not see any crash report even I have follow this guide https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features

Any one having the same problem? Any help is much appreciate. Is there other crash report that work good with new Xcode (for both Objective-C and Swift)?

edit: I have tested on both real devices and simulator (IOS 10.1.1) this is the error log on simulator

```
2016-11-14 13:57:22.426 testFabric[35202:1038257] [Fabric] Unable to locate application icon
2016-11-14 13:57:22.428 testFabric[35202:1038257] [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.3 (120)
2016-11-14 13:57:24.111 testFabric[35202:1038554] [Fabric] failed to download settings Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/vic.testFabric/settings?build_version=1&display_version=1.0&instance=257dd62d2de87b617f4b3e934867b2cd6878c05b&source=1, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/vic.testFabric/settings?build_version=1&display_version=1.0&instance=257dd62d2de87b617f4b3e934867b2cd6878c05b&source=1}
```

On real devices this is what i get when enable crashlytics.debugmode

```
2016-11-14 14:19:36.814181 testFabric2016[967:430996] [Fabric] Unable to locate application icon
2016-11-14 14:19:36.815645 testFabric2016[967:430996] [Crashlytics] Version 3.8.3 (120)
2016-11-14 14:19:36.816032 testFabric2016[967:430996] [Crashlytics] Running on iPad5,3, 10.1.1 (14B150)
2016-11-14 14:19:36.850725 testFabric2016[967:430996] [Answers] Initialized
2016-11-14 14:19:36.851992 testFabric2016[967:430996] [Fabric] Initialized with kit versions: {
    "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.3.3";
    "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.8.3";
    "io.fabric.sdk.ios" = "1.6.11";
}
2016-11-14 14:19:36.864306 testFabric2016[967:431032] [Answers] Answers is disabled. Cleaning up.
2016-11-14 14:19:36.926100 testFabric2016[967:431055] [Answers] Attempting to log app_crashed
2016-11-14 14:19:36.974061 testFabric2016[967:431035] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Packaged report with id 'f3849dbf4d604578ae33ea18e1e51a95' for submission
2016-11-14 14:19:36.974282 testFabric2016[967:431035] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
2016-11-14 14:19:36.974594 testFabric2016[967:431035] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting async /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A145672F-A9A1-4BDF-9499-84E4B101F12A/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/vic.testFabric2016/v3/prepared/53EFFE32-31F1-464A-9D2B-BC5D66D9A67E.multipartmime
2016-11-14 14:19:39.077409 testFabric2016[967:431033] [Fabric] settings downloaded successfully
2016-11-14 14:19:39.078983 testFabric2016[967:431033] [Fabric] Settings are available for consumption
2016-11-14 14:19:41.266751 testFabric2016[967:431032] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] completed submission of /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A145672F-A9A1-4BDF-9499-84E4B101F12A/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.data/vic.testFabric2016/v3/prepared/53EFFE32-31F1-464A-9D2B-BC5D66D9A67E.multipartmime
2016-11-14 14:19:41.268132 testFabric2016[967:431032] [Crashlytics:Crash] report submission successful
```

Comment: does your app support bitcode?

Comment: Hi what is bitcode? Should we enable or disable it?

Comment: Its newer ios feature, you can see weather you have `Bitcode enabled` in build settings, default it's YES. Also, check your fabric dashboard to see if it said `missing dSYMS` or not

Comment: Are you checking the crashes on Simulator or real device ?

Comment: Hi I have edit the question to include scenario with real device an simulator. I have also check bitcode is enable and no missing dSYMS on fabric dasboard

Comment: Have you added the run script of crashlytics to your app?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help the crash report working fine now (after 8,9 hour. May be new project need sometime to report)

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh I have same issue and my fabric dashboard says missing dSYMS what should I do? can you please help me?

Comment: May be in the build setting. search for dSYMs. The correct setting should be Dwarf with dSYMS

Comment: @LêKhánhVinh Thanks Its working from your solution. Thanks and +1 for support.